# QRegExp capture and replace

Tags: qt, qregexp

I have a string

```
    @echo Setting environment for using the GDAL Utilities.
    set GDAL_PATH="G:\MapTiler"
    @echo GDAL path is %GDAL_PATH%.
    set PATH=%GDAL_PATH%;%PATH%
```

in this i want to extract "G:\MapTiler" and replace it with "c:\gdal\bin"

for that i need QRegExp.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the QString::replace() method for this:

```
QString gdalPath;
gdalPath.replace(QRegExp("G:\\MapTiler"),"c:\\gda\\bin");
```

But if the string being replaced does not even change, do not use regex, use string replace:

```
gdalPaht.replace("G:\\MapTiler","c:\\gda\\bin");
```

Edit for changing paths:

```
QString::replace(QRegExp("set GDAL_PATH=\"[^\"]*\""),"set GDAL_PATH=\"c:\\gda\\bin\"");
```

Comment: actually "G:\MapTiler" and "c:\\gda\\bin" is not fixed it can be any path

Comment: Then use ``QString::replace(QRegExp("set GDAL_PATH=\"[^\"]*\""),"set GDAL_PATH=\"c:\\gda\\bin\"");`` The bracket ``[^\"]*`` means anything but the double-qoute sign.

Comment: Hi Sebastian , i need something like this QRegExp exp("GDAL_PATH=\"*\"");

Comment: Just edited the comment to explain the bracket, this should work :)

Comment: where i can find variety of Qregexp examples

Comment: You will find a lot of examples for general "Regular Expressions", these can be taken for Qt also (at least almost all found examples). I am actually using the cheat sheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ for setting up the expressions. You can test your expression in any online regex tester as for example http://regexpal.com/